# How do I create a DIV with Jquery around this pre-exisitining code?

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the code I have, hopefully the selection I've given is enough.

```
var $nextHtml = $('<a href="" class="bx-next">next</a>');
var $prevHtml = $('<a href="" class="bx-prev">prev</a>');
```

The code above creates two links:

```
<a href="">next</a><a href="">prev</a>
```

Right now, the two anchor tags this has created are floating freely within it's parent div, which also holds many other objects.  This makes it hard to stylize the two anchors together.

How can I wrap the two anchors in a div together so the output HTML is this:

```
<div class="control-wrap">
    <a href="">next</a><a href="">prev</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help! My lack of Jquery knowledge is killing me...

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<div>").addClass("control-wrap").append($nextHtml).append($prevHtml);
```